Pytorch Encoder not working
I have a problem understanding how Pytorch and Pytorch-Lightning work. I'm trying to build a toy Autoencoder and it giving me the typical mat1 and mat2 error. My code is:
import torch
from torch import Tensor
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.optim import AdamW
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule, Trainer
import numpy as np

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(100, 64), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(64, 32))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.l1(x)

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(32, 64), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(64, 100))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.l1(x)


encoder = Encoder()
decoder = Decoder()

t = torch.tensor(np.random.random(100))
encoder.forward(t)

When I run the code I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-53b4b6e59a61> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 t = torch.tensor(np.random.random(100))
      5 #t_new = t.reshape(-1,1)
----> 6 encoder.forward(t)
      7 #x.view(x.size(0), -1)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    114 
    115     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 116         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    117 
    118     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype, but got Double and Float

which I can't understand as I haven't set the datatypes. I expect to get a tensor full of 32 zeros (because I haven't put the values of my weights and biases).
Thank you!

No,
you misunderstood the error.
The
np.random.random(100)

generates 100 random number of type float64 (also double in your case).
Change the type to float32 by adding the following line:
t = torch.tensor(np.random.random(100))
t = t.astype(np.float32)
...


Ok, see. your solution was in the right direction but in my version of Pytorch was not correct @Dave. I had to change t = torch.tensor(np.random.random(100)) to t = torch.tensor(np.random.random(100)).float() and now the types matches.

Nice, that it worked. Then do not forget to leave a like at least!
